# JMeter pass JSON response value to next request

Tags: testing, jmeter, http-request-parameters, json-extract

I am using JMETER to test a web app.

First I perform a http GET request which returns a JSON array such as:

```
[
  {
    "key1": 
    {
      "subKey": 
      [
        9.120968,
        39.255417
      ]
    },
    key2 : 1

  },
  {
    "key1": 
    {
      "subKey": 
      [
        9.123852,
        39.243237
      ]
    },
    key2 : 10
  }

]
```

Basically I want to take randomly one element, take the elements of `key1` and create 2 variables in JMeter that will be used for the next query (if randomly it is not possible than just the 1st element).

I tried using `JSON Extractor` with the following settings (the example shows a single variable case):

[image]

and in the next http GET request referencing the parameter as `${var1}`.

How to set `JSON Extractor` to extract a value, save into a JMeter variable to be used in the next http GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Correct JSON Path query would be something like:

   ```
   $..key1.subKey[${__Random(0,1,)}]
   ```
2. You need to switch `Apply to` value either to `Main sample only` or to `Main sample and sub-samples`

   [image]

In the above setup:

- Match No: `0` - tells JMeter to get random value from `key1` subkey
- [`${__Random(0,1,)}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - gets a random element from the array, i.e. `9.120968` or `39.255417`

More information:

- [Jayway Jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not clear enough. I want to pick a random element from the most external array so that it will look like  `{
    "key1": 
    {
      "subKey": 
      [
        9.120968,
        39.255417
      ]
    },
    key2 : 1
.
  }` and from here extract both values from `subKey`

Comment: Then go for `$..key1.subKey` only

Comment: I kept the 0 though to extract a random element and it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

"JMeter variable name to use" option that you've switched on there means that you'd be examining the content of this variable INSTEAD of Sample result.

So the fix is obvious: if you intend to extract whatever you extracting from Sample result - change it back to it.

PS If you intend the opposite (process the variable content, not the sample result) - let me know please.